# General points to remember while doing URL Rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

Im using urlrewritingnet for url re-writing.

Can some one suggest me links out there which can list out points needs to be careful while doing this. As i've seen in many places developer gets into the problem when using it.

How does a complete List of url rewriting looks like.
What all url rules needs to be covered in that file?

As i'm a newbie to this. i dont want to repeat any of the mistake and want to use url rewriting just for better SEO (this is the only one benefit i know)

hope i'm clear what im asking for.

Comment: have you tried this                            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx               and this                                            https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-complete-url-rewriting-solution-for-asp.net-2.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try out:

1. ASP.NET Routing
2. IIS 7 URL Rewrite Module

**[ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd535618%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**:

ASP.NET routing enables you to use URLs that do not have to map to specific files in a Web site. Because the URL does not have to map to a file, you can use URLs that are more easily understood by users.

**[URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)**:

The Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS 7 and above enables IIS administrators to create powerful customized rules to map request URLs to friendly URLs that are easier for users to remember and easier for search engines to find. You can use the URL Rewrite module to perform URL manipulation tasks, some of which include:

- Define powerful rules to transform complex URLs into simple and consistent Web addresses.
- Easily replace Web application URLs to produce user and search engine friendly results.
- Rewrite URLs based on HTTP headers and IIS server variables.
- Perform redirects, send custom responses, or stop HTTP requests based on the logic expressed in the rewrite rules.
- Control access to Web site content based on URL segments or request metadata.